# What is the demonic, psychic and cybernetic distribution in Kaidan?

Tags: the-secret-world

In the secret world, issue 9, which sections of kaidan are psychic, cybernetic or demonic, is there a north east south west way to visualise this or is it more involved than that? If I want to seek out mobs of each type, where should I go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I decided to make a helpful map to outline the key blocks:

- The Demonic mobs occupy Northern Kaidan, centering on the Bathhouse and extending across to the Ginpachi park where the Deep Ones are. The mobs in the instances for Contract Killers and The Right of Way are also Demonic.
- In the South-West, centered on the Fear Nothing building and the Orochi building are the Cybernetic filth and robots.
- In the South-East, centered on the Dream Palace and the ramshackle Nagahama District around it, are the Psychic filth and ghosts. The mobs in the instances for Spiral and The Pachinko Model are also Psychic.

[image: Map]